# Alternative to Excel SUM in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (i.e df1) with the below values. I wanted to SUM Row 4 to 9 and put the resulting value in Row3. How can we achieve it? In excel it has been simple SUM formula like this =SUM(B9:B14) but what is the alternative in pandas?

```
Detail  Value
0   Day 23
1   Month   Aug
2   Year    2020
3   Total Tickets   NaN
4   Pune    2
5   Mumbai  3
6   Thane   33
7   Kolkatta    NaN
8   Hyderabad   NaN
9   Kerala  283
```

Comment: `tot = df.loc[4:10, 'Value'].sum(); df.loc[3, 'Value']=tot`?

Comment: you'll be much better off if each column has a semantic meaning.  E.g., Day/month/year/region should each be separate columns.

Comment: Following from this, say you had columns "Date", "Region", "Value" you can return your total for each date with `df.groupby("Date").sum()`.

Comment: Can you post a working program including the creation of the dataframe with your attempt. We shouldn't have to recreate your data to test it.

Comment: Those first lines shouldn't be part of the dataframe in the first place. Columns should hold  a single type of data so they can be handled collectively. If this came from a CSV for example, you could pull those lines out into a python dict as metadata and then in `read_csv()` use the `skiprows` paramater to leave them out. Now `sum` becomes `df["Value"].sum()` without the complication of skipping rows.